# What Vulkan swapchain does to the window system default framebuffer

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, x11, vulkan

I have few confusions about vulkan surface and its relation to swapchain and window system. As i have understood VkSurface is an abstraction of window and VkSwapchain is a frame buffers collection that we can present on this window. But as far as i concerned, X11 window system creates a default frame buffer along with window creation. So what happens with this default frame buffer when we create a swapchain? Is it included in a swapchain or deleted? Or maybe swapchain is a wrapper around frame buffers which window system has already created?

Comment: X11 itself is a specification, how it is implemented can vary, the same is for Vulkan. Due to that you can only say how it is done for a certain combination of OS, X11, and Vulkan implementation. There are for sure things that are more likely than others, but there is no general answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC there is no "default framebuffer". The swapchain just creates the number of pixmaps you ask for, and with Present X extension it is similar to how Vulkan abstracts it. You present any of them at will, and X will give you an event when the image gets "idle" and can be used again by you. You can look this stuff up in the [mesa driver source code](https://github.com/mesa3d/mesa/blob/master/src/vulkan/wsi/wsi_common_x11.c).